# How can I pass multiple values to dialog box on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass multiple values to the dialog box when the dialog button is clicked. Right now I can only pass one value with button click. I need to pass two values to be used inside the dialog box. The code I have written.

```
<span><button class=" aui-button dialog-show-button-deliverables" id ="div.impact-$j" style="float: left" value="$discoverImpactConfs.get($j).impact"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-add">Add</span></button>$discoverImpactConfs.get($j).impact</span>
```

Open Dialog Code

```
  AJS.$(".dialog-show-button-deliverables").click(function() {


        AJS.dialog2("#deliverables-dialog").show();
        console.log("Getting the button value");
        buttonIdParts = $( this ).attr('id');
        actor_value = document.getElementById(buttonIdParts).value;

        AJS.log(buttonIdParts)
        AJS.log(actor_value)*/

    });
```

Right Now I can only pass one value. I tried adding a hidden input type but it shows the first value it saves.

```
var buttonActor = $(".hiddenActorValue").attr('id');
AJS.log(buttonActor)
```

Please suggest a way how can I achieve this.

Comment: Right Now I am putting that in a comma separated values and then putting them inside array by splitting on comma. Though it works but I am not sure whether it's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Can it is possible to save values in `$.data` like follows:

Before opening Dialog; set the data as:

```
$(".dialog-show-button-deliverables").data("key1", "value1");
$(".dialog-show-button-deliverables").data("key2", "value2");
```

and inside button `click` handler read it like:

```
var data1 = $( this ).data("key1");
var data2 = $( this ).data("key2");
```